# Why the static accessed list gets updated even if we assign this to local

Tags: java

```
public static void Method1(String a)
{
    List<DataBean> list = new ArrayList<DataBean>();
    list = StaticClass.masterList; // it has prepopulated list item


    for (JavaBean bean: list) {
        //Some condition and we call bean.setters 

    }

}
```

Why here the `StaticClass.masterList` gets updated in for loop I called the update on bean although?

Comment: Because `resultList` and `masterList` point to the same object.

Comment: is there a way i can just read the masterList and copy and then process so that it will not change just copy changes

Comment: @Karn_way You can copy the masterlist's elements into list, but when those elements will be the same. That is, even if you copy `masterList`'s elements into `list`, each `bean` in `list` is also in `masterList`.  You'll see the changes in each `bean` regardless of whether you access it through `list` or `masterList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to the list is what you are copying and that doesn't get updated.

What can get updated in the object it references.

Note:

```
List<DataBean> list = new ArrayList<DataBean>();
```

Here `list` is not a `List` , it is just a reference to a list which is why you can assign it to a new object.

If you want to take a shallow copy of the masterList you can do.

```
List<DataBean> list = new ArrayList<DataBean>(StaticClass.masterList);
```

This way if you alter the list, it will not change the master.  However, if you alter one of DataBeans, this will be visible.  If you need a deep copy you can do

```
List<DataBean> list = new ArrayList<DataBean>();
for (DataBean db: StaticClass.masterList)
     list.add(new DataBean(db));
```

Comment: Second sentence, in = is, I believe?

Comment: please guide me the way i will not let update the masterList just read and process with new List can we do this?

Comment: But even if @Karn_way copies `StaticClass.masterList`'s elements into `list`, they'll still have the same elements, so changes made to them (e.g., by `list.get(i).setField(42)`) will still be ’visible’ through `StaticClass.masterList.get(i)`.  It's not just that the lists are the same, but that the _objects_ **in** the lists are the same, too.

Comment: @Karn_way You need to take a copy of what you are changing.  How much you copy depends on what are you changing.  See some examples in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because `list` and `StaticClass.masterList` will reference the same object.

So if you call setters on any object in `list` you'll see the changes in `StaticClass.masterList` as well.

Comment: is there a way in above code to avoid masterList update but just list?

Comment: You have to copy its contents to the new list (that means cloning the old list's contents)